# Waves Native Power Pack

Tags: waves, pro-tools, plug-ins, native

Right now Sweetwater is selling this package for $180. I don't have any Waves plug-ins and am still using the EQ and D-Verb that came with Pro Tools. Would this be a wise investment?

Answer (score 1):

It's $168.75 at Amazon. http://www.amazon.com/Waves-Native-Power-Pack-Standard/dp/B0007CG5DC

Renn Axe, Q10 and L1 are GREAT plug-ins! I say, go for it if you've got the money available.

Comment: Thanks for the link my man. Just snatched it. What are some other plug-ins you'd recommend when I get some extra cash? 

Comment: @Mitchell You're welcome! I highly recommend the Oxford EQ and Dynamics and Limiter. But, depends on what your priority is for what type of projects you'll be doing. What sorts of things do you work on or design for?

Comment: I've been working on different sorts of projects. Right now I'm working on a stop-motion animation short where I have to do some raw/organic sounding Foley work. Other projects that I'll be starting to work on soon will be mostly indie short films with not too many crazy SFX going on. Mostly ambience, foley, and hopefully not too much dialogue clean-up. I suppose I should probably invest in Izotope RX2 sometime soon haha.

Comment: Yeah. Izotope RX is an excellent choice. But as for workhorse EQ and dynamics, I highly recommend the Oxford plug-ins. Me and my coworkers use them every day.

Answer (score 1):

The Native Power Pack is a great bundle. It's one of the first Waves bundles I bought & you get some very powerful tools worth twice that price (which is roughly what I paid years & years ago). It's also a good way to get in on the upgrade path: cheap buy-in, great tools for the time being, good value on the trade up. If the wallet's fat from tax refunds buy it.

Comment: Did that too (paid an arm and a leg back then too), then eventually upgraded to Gold. Honestly don't see going beyond Gold for post work, it seems to come with everything one needs and not a lot of fluff

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go for it, at that price. I still rate digi eq over Q10, but i couldn't live without L1. It's also good to have a reverb that's a little more sophisticated than Dverb, although i still think Dverb is a great tool if you use it right.

Comment: Nothing better than a non-lin D-Verb on a snare sometimes ;-)

Comment: @Utopia You mean Disgusting-Verb? ;)